# Choose proxy based on URL

Tags: browser, proxy

I was wondering whether theres a possibility in todays common browser's to switch the Proxy based on the URL-Pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: yes its possible for e.g consider http://getfoxyproxy.org/patterns.html u can find reference

Comment: I have seen this, but isn't it only available in the paid version?

Comment: This question has already been answered http://superuser.com/questions/614132/how-to-use-different-proxy-for-different-address
You can use a PAC.

Comment: so u need like browser addons which switch proxy based on url pattern?

Comment: No. Have a look at my comment.

Comment: @Chris that question relates to changing proxy at windows,this question is about the browser

Comment: I wasnt aware that PAC allows for this sort of complexity in its configuration - will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you, to use the [FoxyProxy-addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) for the Firefox together with a [PAC-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_Auto-Config).

FoxyProxy uses your standard PAC-file:

Excerpt from FoxyProxy-FAQ

> When you configure a proxy in FoxyProxy and select "Automatic proxy
>   configuration URL" on the "Proxy Details" page, you're specifying that
>   FoxyProxy use a PAC for any patterns associated with this proxy
>   configuration. In other words, for each URL that matches a URL pattern
>   defined by a proxy configuration specified to use a PAC, FoxyProxy
>   calls that PAC's FindProxyForURL() implementation. The return value of
>   FindProxyForURL() determines which proxy (if any) is used.

**You can add different proxies for different urls to the PAC-File.**

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
        // our local URLs from the domains below example.com don't need a proxy:
        if (shExpMatch(host, "*.example.com"))
        {
                return "DIRECT";
        }

        // URLs within this network are accessed through
        // port 8080 on fastproxy.example.com:
        if (isInNet(host, "10.0.0.0", "255.255.248.0"))
        {
                return "PROXY fastproxy.example.com:8080";
        }

        // All other requests go through port 8080 of proxy.example.com.
        // should that fail to respond, go directly to the WWW:
        return "PROXY proxy.example.com:8080; DIRECT"; 
}
```